# How to remove certain cols's value on certain rows

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to know whether there is a simple way to remove the values for all cols except ID for the first two rows (replace it with "")? As many ways as possible. Many thanks.

Sample data can be build using codes :

```
df<-structure(list(ID = structure(c("C5-102", "C5-102", "C5-102", 
"C5-102", "C5-102", "C5-102", "C5-102", "C5-102", "C5-102", "C5-102", 
"C1-103", "C1-103", "C1-103", "C1-103", "C1-103", "C1-103", "C1-103", 
"C1-103", "C8-104", "C8-104", "C8-104", "C8-104", "C8-104", "C8-104"
), label = "Unique Subject Identifier", format.sas = "$"), score = c(73.8, 
100, 147.6, 73.8, 147.6, 73.8, 147.6, 1600, 1600, 1600, 64.5, 
129, 64.5, 129, 64.5, 129, 4302, 86, 62.7, 125.4, 62.7, 125.4, 
62.7, 125.4), test = c("A", "M", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", 
"C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "M", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A"), Time = c("2016-03-16T10:22", "2016-03-25T01:23", 
"2016-03-16T11:10", "2016-03-17T12:12", "2016-03-17T12:52", "2016-03-18T12:05", 
"2016-03-18T12:53", "2016-03-21T11:00", "2016-03-22T11:55", "2016-03-23T12:34", 
"2016-08-09T14:13", "2016-08-09T14:49", "2016-08-10T13:30", "2016-08-10T14:30", 
"2016-08-12T13:35", "2016-08-12T14:20", "2016-08-14T13:00", "2016-08-18T01:00", 
"2016-08-11T14:38", "2016-08-11T15:42", "2016-08-12T14:22", "2016-08-12T15:26", 
"2016-08-13T14:31", "2016-08-13T15:45")), row.names = c(NA, -24L
), label = "EX                              ", class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be better to replace with `NA` instead of `""` as `""` is a character string and it changes the `type` of the column while `NA` is a missing value and doesn't change the type

```
df[1:2, -1] <- NA
```

In the above code, we specify the row/column index separated by `,` i.e. we are selecting rows 1 and 2, and  columns other than the first one.  Once selected, then do the assignment (`<-`) to `NA`

The above code is concise, simple and is a `base R` option

---

Another option is `replace` with `mutate/across` and if need to create a new column with `unite`, then use the `na.rm = TRUE` (as by default it is `FALSE`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
     mutate(across(-1, ~ replace(., 1:2, NA))) %>%
     unite(score, test, Time, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: I will need to use sth like `unite("TotalScore","Score","Score1",sep = " ") ` later. after I cbine another dataset. Will `NA` show up as NA or "" in this case?

Comment: @Statq, you can use `na.rm = TRUE` in `unite` as the usage is `unite(data, col, ..., sep = "_", remove = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)`